# the report has no tables, i am using datatable to pass data to crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //dt.TableName = "reportTable";
            int optn=int.Parse(Request.QueryString["optn"].ToString());
            if (optn == 2)
            {
                DateTime frm = DateTime.Parse(Request.QueryString["from"].ToString());
                DateTime to = DateTime.Parse(Request.QueryString["to"].ToString());
                dt=commn.Returndt(optn, frm, to);
            }
            else
            {
                dt = commn.Returndt(optn);
            }

            //DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            //ds.Tables[0].Merge(dt);
            //ds.Tables.Add(dt);
            //SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
            //da.Fill(ds, dt.TableName.ToString());
            string xmlpath = Server.MapPath(@"Reports\abc.xml");
            dt.WriteXmlSchema(xmlpath);
            ReportDocument cryRpt = new ReportDocument();
            cryRpt.Load(Server.MapPath(@"Reports\rptContractor.rpt"));
            cryRpt.SetDataSource(dt);
            CRViewer.ReportSource = cryRpt;
```

i am trying to get data from a database to a datatable (dt) by using stored procedure. but when i pass this datatable to crystal report, it will generate error : The report has no tables.
can any one give me solution for this...

Comment: How is your report set up?  Have you configured the data sources within your report?

Comment: no, i am just using a blank report

Comment: Problem is solved... thanks for your response.
I am just forgetting one step, that is to include XML file...